# Add integers to duplicate values in array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I go about getting all of the duplicate values in an array, and assigning an integer to each of them to make them unique. For example:

```
array(
    0 => 'Title',
    1 => 'Primary Contact: Name',
    2 => 'Primary Contact: Email',
    3 = > 'Title',
    4 = > 'Title'
);
```

My goal is to turn that into the following:

```
array(
    0 => 'Title - 1',
    1 => 'Primary Contact: Name',
    2 => 'Primary Contact: Email',
    3 = > 'Title - 2',
    4 = > 'Title - 3'
);
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: I've been messing around with using array_count_values and filtering through the array using a for loop, targeting each element greater than 1, but I haven't managed to get to the solution I need yet.

Comment: ^ Then add your attempt to your question!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a foreach to integrate through the array and use array_keys with the search option to check for the value in the array and update it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php